# Astronomy / Physics discussion on topic distinction

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

We've had some [sporadic discussions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/astronomy-astrophyiscs-related-question-here) about how to determine the topic boundary between Astronomy.SE and Physics.SE and what kinds of questions should be transferred over to the astro site. They've also had some discussions on the same topic. So we thought it would be a good idea to get everyone together and work out how to draw the boundary between the two sites.

There will be a chat event in the Astronomy chat room this Friday at 1600 UTC (noon EDT). If you're free at that time, please consider dropping in!

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/815/colloquium?tab=schedule